# When can a ChannelFactory's state become faulted?

Tags: c#, wcf, channelfactory

I'm currently working with WCF and looking for best practices for managing client channels and factories.  I've seen a fair amount for `ClientChannel` objects, but what about `ChannelFactory`?  It is a `CommunicationObject`.  In theory it could go into a faulted state, but is this actually possible?  Or is it reasonable to expect a `ChannelFactory` to always be able to create useable channels after instantiation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WCF ChannelFactory State Property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011483/wcf-channelfactory-state-property)

Comment: Yeah... I guess I was looking for a little more.  The reply with the most votes states that there's a lot of initialization that's done at the beginning, which could cause a bad state, but I was to know if anyone else had seen a factory go into a bad state for any other reason.  I was also wondering if it was ok, then, to let a factory live forever.